# Can't export an svg image in the same form as in figma

Tags: css, svg, figma, mix-blend-mode

I have a figma layout: https://www.figma.com/file/IyFsfoAQOr3qCrHFeSLs0r/Cryptopia-(Copy)?node-id=0%3A1&mode=dev. All the svg files I export don't look the same as on the layout. I understand that this has something to do with mix-blend-mode, but I don't understand what needs to be done. Or is it some kind of figma bug?  Please help

I am trying to export this svg (the first picture), but on my website it looks like in the second picture.

[image: Layout svg]

[image: My svg]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but everything has worked when I inserted svg through "use". Also it works when svg inserts right in html. Before I used only img and background. Hope it will be helpful for someone

```
<svg>
  <use xlink:href="assets/icons/bitcoin-background.svg#bitcoin" />
</svg>
```